# Does "official" mean governor or officer in some situations?

Tags: meaning

A [Financial Times post](https://www.ft.com/content/a06f414c-0e6e-11e9-a3aa-118c761d2745) says

> China has asked **officials** to stop mentioning its premier programme to recruit the brightest tech talent from overseas, after growing suspicions over the scheme from the US.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/official) gives this definition

> a person who has a position of responsibility in an organization:

In the quotation, does "officials" refer to the Chinese officers or the governors in the US?

Comment: There's no mention of any governors. It seems to mean *Chinese* officials. Your first link only works if we subscribe to the FT, by the way :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you. Does "Chinese officials" mean the officers, the part of the Chinese government?

Comment: Yes, "Chinese officials" means people with positions of responsibility or authority in the Chinese government, just as your definition from Cambridge Dictionary says.